# form data moves through ajax on page load instead of on submit

Tags: ajax, forms, upload, multipartform-data, form-data

I am sure there are things I haven't read out there, but every search I do just turns up purple links. My goal is to have a form that uses ajax in order to avoid page refresh and avoid submit on manual page refresh. I want to both upload a file and insert data into the database table. I actually have this part down. The problem is that the action is started on page load. I think this is because my ajax function uses #multiform).submit, but if I change that to #submit).submit then the ajax script doesn't send the data to upload.php and I just end up with a blank array being passed to upload.php.

I can make the upload work on click with a button instead of an input for the form submit. That's all without using formdata though. I need to use formdata to also upload the file. The below script does work. I just need it to work after clicking submit, and not automatically when the page loads.

As I'm learning, I'm thinking that formObj=$(this) is referring to the multiform and grabbing the objects, so when I change multiform to submit (this) doesn't work anymore. Is it possible that I just need to change that field somehow? I've been working on this non stop for weeks. I keep getting closer, but still not there. Please help me. Thank you.

my form:

```
<form name="multiform" id="multiform" action="upload.php" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
Name: <input type="text" name="dname"  value="Ravi"/> <br/>
Age :<input type="text" name="age"  value="1" /> <br/>
Image :<input type="file" name="photo" /><br/>
<input type="submit" id="submit" value="Ajax File Upload" />
</form>
```

my js:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
$("#multiform").submit(function(e)
{
var formObj = $(this);
var formURL = formObj.attr("action");
var formData = new FormData($(this)[0]); 

$.ajax({
    url: formURL,
type: 'POST',
    data:  formData,
mimeType:"multipart/form-data",
contentType: false,
    cache: false,
    processData:false,
success: function(data, textStatus, jqXHR)
{ alert(data)

},
 error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) 
 {
 }          
});

e.preventDefault(); //Prevent Default action. 
}); 

$("#multiform").submit(); //Submit the form
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured this out by looking at it backwards. I googled how to make the form submit automatically on page load and found out that $(document).submit() makes a form submit on page load, so I took out $("#multiform").submit(); and now it works. An added note to anyone else who might find this and be working on something similar. For some reason, having an id of submit for input type submit causes the name and age variables to be ignored.